# angularfire2, push/update data to specific child/key only

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have a function to push data and I another two properties that have to be pushed/updated/stored to same key. There are `percentMale` and `percentFemale`. I need to put the submitted result for these two properties in a same child/key. Let's say the key is `L2Jq0Tg4JOS66F786pT`.

```js
male: number = 0;
female: number = 0;
percentMale;
percentFemale;
insertdata(data: App) {
  if (data.data1 == 'Male') {
    this.male++;
  } else if (data.data1 == 'Female') {
    this.female++;
  }
  this.percentMale = this.male / (this.male + this.female) * 100;
  console.log('percentMale', this.percentMale + '%');

  this.percentFemale = this.female / (this.male + this.female) * 100;
  console.log('percentFemale', this.percentFemale + '%');

  this.dataList.push({
    data1: data.data1,
    data2: data.data2,
    data3: data.data3,
    time: new Date().getTime(),
  });

  this.dataList.push({
    percentMale: this.percentMale,
    percentFemale: this.percentFemale,
  });

  //if a key already exist
  //this.dataList.update(data.$key, {
  //percentMale: this.percentMale,
  //percentFemale: this.percentFemale,
  //});
}
```

The function i made causes more `percentMale` and `percentFemale` are stored separately and the table shows unnecessary rows.

[image]

can anyone help me figure this out please? please let me know if more snippets are needed.

Comment: can you share your expected firebase data structure...?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.

```js
this.pertanyaanList.update("databaseKey", {
      percentMale: this.percentMale,
      percentFemale: this.percentFemale,
      });
```